# Export Exchange Distribution List as SMTP

Tags: exchange, smtp, export, distribution-lists

I am looking for a way to export an Exchange 2007 Distribution List to SMTP addresses.
Ideally a VB or PowerShell script that lets me specify the list I am interested in and returns the list of members' smtp addresses is what I am looking for.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the primary SMTP address is enough:

```
Get-DistributionGroupMember <List Name> | fl PrimarySmtpAddress
```

If it isn't:

```
Get-DistributionGroupMember <List Name> | fl EmailAddresses
```

(The last one will also include non-SMTP addresses, so it may require some post-processing.)

---

### Edit:

The best course of action would be to use the Exchange Management Shell, which is built for that; but if you can't use it, standard PowerShell can still help you:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADGroupMember <List Name> | Get-ADUser -Properties EmailAddress | fl EmailAddress
```

Comment: That's Exchange Management Shell (PowerShell with Exchange-specific cmdlets).

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I don't have access to the Exchange Management Tools.  Is there another method to access this remotely without installing them?

Comment: @RobM: See edit.